# Error while trying to access files in the app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, expo

I'm building a react-native app that uses tensorflow to recognize images, I'm following the steps in this [tutorial](https://github.com/reneweb/react-native-tensorflow).

I did everything according to the explanations, including the part of **"Fetching files"**. I created the assets folder and put the files in it (the path is correct).

But when I run this code:

```
const tfImageRecognition = new TfImageRecognition({
    model: require('./assets/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb'),
    labels: require('./assets/tensorflow_labels.txt'),
});
```

The app gives the following error:

[image]

I already tried to create a new project, I imported the react-native-tensorflow `import { TfImageRecognition } from 'react-native-tensorflow';`, I updated the cache, I deleted the folder node_modules and also I created the file "*rn-cli.config.js*" that is requested in the tutorial to give access to the files in the assets folder. Any idea how to fix this?

I'm using [expo](https://expo.io/) to run the app on mobile (android).

- npm: 5.51
- expo: 51.4.0
- react-native: 0.54.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: Are you sure that the " . " in " ./assets/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb " refers to the same directory that you expect it to refer to?  You could try to print/verify the root directory... or try entering the full file path for troubleshooting purposes.  That seems to be the only explanation to me.

Comment: You can try adding var modelFile = require('./assets/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb'); and var labelFile = require('./assets/tensorflow_labels.txt'); and then assign these variables in the models and labels properties.

Answer (score 1):

This problem didn't occur with me. Try `react-native start --reset-cache`  and then run the app again.

Comment: I tried this and continue the same error, I already tried to create a new project and the error continued, thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to this.

```
import model from './assets/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb';
import labels from './assets/tensorflow_labels.txt';

const tfImageRecognition = new TfImageRecognition({
    model,
    labels
});
```

Restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same example as you mentioned I got accessed Image and Text.
I stored files inside `assets` in the same directory. Can you share code to produce an error that you faced?

```
  async recognizeImage() {

    try {
      const tfImageRecognition = new TfImageRecognition({
        model:require('./assets/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb'),
        labels: require('./assets/tensorflow_labels.txt')
      })

      const results = await tfImageRecognition.recognize({
        image: this.image
      })

      const resultText = `Name: ${results[0].name} - Confidence: ${results[0].confidence}`
      this.setState({result: resultText})

      await tfImageRecognition.close()
    } catch(err) {
      alert(err)
    }
  }
```

As you mentioned your using `expo` then I'm assuming that run `npm eject` already. As `react-native-tensorflow` this library require native changes

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I will test your tips as soon as possible. If you want to take a look at the [code](https://github.com/mathiasfc/AppLeitorDeCedulas/blob/master/App.js) or even the [project](https://github.com/mathiasfc/AppLeitorDeCedulas), you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

You must add extensions in your rn-cli.config.js, in order to require tensorflow_inception_graph.pb and tensorflow_labels.txt

```
module.exports = {
  getAssetExts() {
    return ['pb', 'txt']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ./ with so ../ , so final code will be -

```
  model: require('../assets/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb'),
  labels: require('../assets/tensorflow_labels.txt')
```